# Error: fs.js:47 } = primordials; ^ ReferenceError: primordials is not defined

Tags: angular, npm

I am facing the following error, my node version is `12.11.1` but
when I run the following command `npm run server` it gives the error as shown below:

```
 fs.js:47
  } = primordials;
      ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
at fs.js:47:5
```

Whereas executing the command `ng serve --o` is quite fine.

Comment: what is supposed to run when you execute `npm run server`? if you need to run your angular app, then just do it with `ng serve`? why do you need `npm run server`?

Comment: @Andres2142 this is to run JSON server

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.  Exactly the same error.  In my case it worked to install the cli again....

npm install -g @angular/cli

Hope it helps :-)